# Best API to get newly listed tokens (Solana)

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, token-2022, development

I am developing a solana bot and would like to recieve newly listed Solana tokens but all the APIs I find are very expensive. Looking to try find a cheaper yet still fast alternative.

Comment: hello, did you find one?